# Strange rotation behavior. Activity updated after rotation, but none of the standard activity lifecycle methods are invoked

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

**Note:** Everything written below is tested in an emulator and on a real device, on different Android versions (7 and 9) and different projects (Kotlin).

When I quick rotate devices from landscape mode (ROTATION_90) immediately to reverse landscape (ROTATION_270) all activity is redrawn correctly, but none of the standard activity lifecycle methods are invoked. Checked in debug mode through breakpoints.

If I rotate a slowly (ROTATION_90 (landscape) -> ROTATION_0 (portrait) -> ROTATION_270 (reverse landscape)) everything is called and works as it should.

I have no attributes in the manifest to override the rotation, like `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` and `override fun onConfigurationChanged`.

I hope someone helps me find the reason for such a strange bug. This is important to me because I need to perform certain actions after rotation.